# set the position of the textbox

Tags: css, asp.net, position

I have 3 textbox as below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtID" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPosition" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

when I zoom in in browser, the textbox on the right will change its position to bottom of the left textbox. can I fix it 3 of them stay to each other and wont change the position when I zoom in in browser.

Comment: Yes you can fix it, but you need to include your HTML and CSS

Comment: I do added position absolute, but its all stacked together.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the textboxes to 33% with styling.

```
.textbox {
 width: 33%;
}
```

If you have no spacing or margin between the textboxes, this should work.

Comment: coz I want to fixed the textbox width as 250px. that is why not using %

Comment: You could set max-width to 250px, and still have the width set to 33% so they break down to 33% if they are less than 250px.